# How do I link Two pages with PHP

Tags: php, html, validation

I am making a website and in my website i have the very firstpage which is just plainly a login page. Now all i have to do is validate users loging using PHP but then i am stuck on how to link the second page to the the Login page so when the user logs in he is redirected to that page. I need Help on that end

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Upon successfully logging in, you will likely want to redirect to the second page using a header redirection.

```
header( "Location: page2.php" );
exit;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if($login == true){
header('location:http://yoursite.com/newindex.php');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2-3 ways to do it

> **IMPORTANT**: You must to check login status in all.php files.

### **1. redirect after login**

You'll send header after login, but dont forget about `ob_start()`

```
<?php
ob_start();
...
if($login) { // your condition
 header('Location: page2.php');
}
```

### **2. if/else inclusion variant**

```
<?php
if(!$loged) {
//show login page
} else {
 include('page2.php'); // or do smth other
}
```

### **3. check login in every page**

include in every page 'login.php' same as if/else variant.

```
<?php //page2.php
if(!$logged) {
 include 'login.php'; 
} else {
....
}
```

Comment: ohh Thank you for the answer. one qucik question so do i have bundle the second page as a php file